# Very simple SQL table query not stopping

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following SQL query, returns 113316 records but doesn't stop running:

```
SELECT * FROM SupportingVideo
```

If I add `TOP 113336` the query completes (returning 113336 records) within a second.  If I change it to `TOP 113337` the query returns the orginal 113316 records and runs indefinitely.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is SupportingVideo a base table or a view?

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't stop running ?

Comment: Run this: `Select count(*) from SupportingVideo`, and tell us the result

Comment: @CharlesBretana Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried that and it didn't stop or return anything.  It's no different to running the initial query.

Comment: @GuidoG the timer, in SQL Management Studio, keeps on ticking. Apologies for not stating that in the question.

Comment: @jarlh it's a table.  Thanks

Comment: Does this table have any indexes?

Comment: @Steven,  Then there might be a row lock or an open transaction creating a row lock on some row (not in the first 113336 rows) of the table.  Does this table have a Primary Key defined? or is it a Heap?

Comment: @MisterPositive yes, clustered on the primary key.

Comment: @Stevan, use `sp_GetAppLock` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx to check if there are locks on the table.

Comment: @CharlesBretana it has an identity primary key.  How would I determine that there is a row lock?  Thanks

Comment: @CharlesBretana thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: @CharlesBretana there aren't any locks on the table. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: Nothing definitive, but If I was facing this issue, the next "shot in the dark" that I'd try, (assuming this table is not online live mission  critical) is I would drop and recreate all the indices. If that didn't work, I'd do a diagnostic on the table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx

Comment: @CharlesBretana many thanks, for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a suspended process blocking other processes.  I used the `sp_who2` stored procedure to find out which process was doing the blocking and then I used the Activity Monitor (In Object Explorer, right click on the server node and then select Activity Monitor) to kill the offending process.